# Can I use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in SignalR hubs, or does SignalR infrastructure rely on SynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have some hub methods that perform I/O operations which I want to call asynchronously.

Is it safe to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in my hub methods, or does SignalR require a captured SynchronizationContext for request info or something like that?

```
    public async Task<Response> Save() {
        // do some prep work
        var response = await SaveThingsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // do something with response
        return response;
    }
```

To clarify: my code does not require thread culture or anything else stored in the SynchronizationContext.
My concern is that the SignalR server code might store information there, such as Client Ids, request infos or the like, which it may not be able to access if the async method is continued from a different thread.

When I tested my method it appeared to work fine, but that doesn't proof anything necessarily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignalR does not depend on `SynchronizationContext`. It is commonly self-hosted in Win32 services (and console apps, for testing), where there is no `SynchronizationContext`.

See also [this SignalR issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2250).

Comment: Accepting this answer because it addresses SignalR specifically.

Answer (score 5):

ConfigureAwait does not remove the sync context. It merely causes the task completion continuation to not use the current sync context.

It is always safe to use if the rest of the current async method does not depend on the sync context. Emphasis on *method* as opposed to *thread*.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last paragraph? In my example, the `Save` method will be continued without the current sync context. When it completes, some async SignalR method will be notified and continued. Could that method restore the sync context (if it were to depend on it), even though the `Save` method did not use the current one? I was under the impression that once I call `ConfigureAwait(false)`, all calling async methods would also be executed without the current sync context.

Comment: The sync context, if any was present, would not be removed. Rather, you'd switch to the thread pool where no sync context is present. Your task completes on the thread pool. Anyone waiting for that task is not affected by where that task completed.